# Trying to build a bar chart. No errors in code, but I don't get the visual

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a simple bar chart in d3, but I have no errors in my code and only get a blank page. I am not sure what is going on as I have used a function from a tutorial to properly format my data. I will include a sample of the csv file as well as the code.

```
BeaconMac,UserMac,Date
Office,Michael Albanese,6-Mar-2015
Office,Michael Albanese,6-Mar-2015
Treatment Room,Michael Albanese,6-Mar-2015
Office,Michael Albanese,6-Mar-2015
Treatment Room,Michael Albanese,6-Mar-2015
Office,Michael Albanese,6-Mar-2015






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(data){
        var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%m/%d/%Y');
        var numberFormat = d3.format('.2f');

        data.forEach(function(d){
            d.dd = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
            d.month = d3.time.month(d.dd);
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.open = +d.open;
        });

        //width and height
        var w = 500;
        var h = 100;

        //the svg element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attribute("width", w)
                .attribute("height", h);
        svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attribute("x", 0)
                .attribute("y", 0)




    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code implies you have a csv with four columns with the headers `date`, `dd`, `close`, and `open`. However your `csv` doesn't look like it has those columns. It has three columns with the headers `BeaconMac`, `UserMac`, and `date`.

I also don't see how you could make a bar chart out of that data. You have a date category and two string categories. In order to make a bar column you would need some numbers.

Comment: I'm relatively new to d3. What are some examples of visualizations that would work for this type of data?

Comment: Visualizations for two categorical variables and one ordinal? That's a tricky one. Can you post more of your example data? I'll see if it can work with a Sankey diagram or a heatmap.

Comment: I can't go in detail regarding the data, but I'm considering adding , via excel since the data set is large, of adding how often each user utilizes the system. Perhaps this would give more options?

Comment: *Disclosure: This is my own website/project.* But I actually think it's pretty helpful to determining the right visualization for your data: http://crclayton.com/projects/graph-chooser/

Comment: Thank you, it helps a great deal! I was a little lost with all of the options out there

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some information to you: a rectangle (rect) has 4 attributes (that you set using .attr): x position, y position, height and width. If you don't set height and width, no visual will show.